# Generate random number and find minimum/maximum as Java Class variables

Tags: java, class, variables, random

I'm a complete Java newbie. I'm working on classes and methods. I'm trying to create a class variable that stores the minimum value for a random number generator.

It has to be a **class** variable instead of being a variable in a method. Any ideas? I thought to use the `Math.random()` generator. Something like:

```
int ranNum = Math.random();
```

This will give me a random number but how would I find the minimum (or maximum) this way?

Comment: Minimum or maximum of what? Your requirements are very unclear.

Comment: Read the [Math.random() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()) and see that the value is between 0 and 1

Comment: What is the range between which you want random number and minimum maximum?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking for this:

```
int min = 50;
int max = 100;
int ranNum = min+(int)(Math.random()*((max-min) + 1));
```

This will generate a random number from min to max (inclusive)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import java.util.Random;
Random rand = new Random();
int i = rand.nextInt( 7 - 0 + 1 ); // where 7 is max and 0 is min
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you Random numbers from 0-100

and also will give you the smallest:

```
 import java.util.Random;

   public class AcademicController 
  {
   private static int i,a=0,small=500;


  public static void main(String[] args)
  { 
    Random ran=new Random();
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)//enter the range here
    {

    a=ran.nextInt(100);//gives you any number from 0-99
    System.out.println(a);

    if(a<small)//if given number is < than previous, make this number small
    small=a;
    }

    System.out.println("small is :"+small);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own random methods based on it.

```
/**
 * Returns a random real number between 0 and x. The number is always
 * smaller than x.
 * 
 * @param x The maximum range
 * @return A random real number
 */
public static int random(int x){
    return (int) (Math.floor(Math.random() * x));
}

/**
 * Returns a random real number between x1 (inclusive) and x2 (exclusive).
 * 
 * @param x1 The inclusive
 * @param x2 The exclusive
 * @return A random real number between x1 and x2
 */
public static int random_range(int x1, int x2){
    return (int) (Math.floor(x1 + (Math.random() * (x2 - x1))));
}
```

Hope these simple methods helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If ypu're just looking to hold state for your class, this might be it:

```
public class MyRandom {

    private static final MyRandom INSTANCE = new MyRandom();

    public static MyRandom getInstance(){
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private int low;

    private int high;

    private Random r = new Random();

    private MyRandom(){

    }

    public int getHigh() {
        return high;
    }

    public int getLow() {
        return low;
    }

    public synchronized int getRandom(){
        int next = r.nextInt();
        if (next < low){
            low = next;
        }
        if (next > high){
            high = next;
        }
        return next;
    }


}
```

Note that this class is singleton and should be used application wide to generate random values.